# What is the best way to create a client-server application with a Java Web Start program?

Tags: java, netbeans, client-server, java-web-start, japplet

Ok so I have created an application, which is a Java Web Start application, but I have determined that I will need to write data to the server machine, hence the need for an additional server application. Pretty much I want the client to send different strings in order to process a clients requests in varying ways (eg create a new user file on the server machine or send user data read from a file to the client machine).

I was thinking of possibly using sockets, but if there is a better way then I'm all for that. Also I assume that whatever I do use, I will need to use threading in order to process many simultaneous requests, is this correct?

Comment: you better create a webservice

Comment: how do I do that? Is that like a Java Web project in netbeans?

Comment: Note that e.g. Glassfish can have clients which run through Java WebStart but which has an umbellical cord back to the application server making it easy to exchange data.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how can this be achieved? A link to a tutorial would be awesome

Comment: also keep in mind that I created the Java Web Start app using Java SE

Comment: Have a look at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jws-glassfish/

Comment: im using netbeans and im unsure how to achieve the above...

Comment: Check out this [site](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/web-services/create-client-server-application-for-web-service-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose you better create a webservice which communicates over http for exchanging data. I would recommend doing this in Java or maybe creating a WCF in C#.

Tutorials in Eclipse for java webservice: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#first_project

In netbeans: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

The first tutorial is a restful service which is pretty popular and easy to grasp.
Good luck!

Comment: so following the netbeans tutorial, I can simply add my existing applet into the web service project? (with some tweaking of course). Also would it be better if I just used the program as an applet or would having it as a java-web-start app be better?

Comment: Your first question, yes it should be that simple. I'm developing with eclipse though. And frankly I can't answer your second question, I don't believe it matters but you must figure that out yourself.

Comment: would this tutorial achieve what i desire? http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html